# Disable debug_kit depending on controller

Tags: cakephp

I am running CakePHP 4.1.4 and what I find in internet and SO, it doesn't work as some answers are 9 years old. I tried this in `config/app.php`

```
    'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', false), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
--- or ---
    'debug' => FALSE,
```

or in `AppController.php`

```
public function initialize(): void
{
    Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

Nothing helps. This icon is still visible in the left lower corner:

[image]

**My question:**

How can I remove it completely for some Controllers, and if it's not possible, then for the whole project.

Comment: The problem aside, why do you want to disable it per route in the first place?

Comment: @ndm I don't really understand what you mean with _disable per route in the first place_. This debug icon shouldn't be visible in the production environment, if this is what you meant.

Comment: The first part of your question is "_how can I remove it completely for some controllers_", which to me implies disabling it for individual routes, instead of disabling it completely, which is what the second part of your question is about.  I'm wondering about the underlying problem that you seemingly want to solve by disabling it for specific controllers only.

Comment: @ndm OK, now I understand you! Sorry! Because some of controllers are now already in production environment and secured by a login so I can differ very accurate.

Comment: I don't really get what that would look like, but Debug Kit generally shouldn't run in the production environment at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `debug` option in the controller layer is too late, the decision whether the Debug Kit plugin is being loaded is by default made in `Application::bootstrap()`, located in `src/Application.php`. Debug Kit itself will also check the `debug` config option, however that also happens before the controller layer is reached, it happens in the middleware layer.

If you've used a recent version of the `cakephp/app` aplication template to create your application, then you should set the `debug` value in `config/app_local.php`, which is being loaded after `config/app.php`, and will set/overwrite some settings with environment specific values.

I don't think there's any overly straight forward way do disable debug kit per route. The plugin will inject the middleware at the top of the middleware stack, above everything else. The closest you can easily get is probably using the [**`DebugKit.ignorePathsPattern` option**](https://book.cakephp.org/debugkit/4/en/index.html#configuration), it accepts a RegEx pattern that is being matched against the current request path. However that *doesn't* really disable Debug Kit, it will just hide it, and not save the debug data that has been captured on that request. Also this will only apply for reponses within the `2xx` status code range.

Long story short, you'll probably have to live with choosing to either enable it, or to disable it.

Comment: I added small code in `config/app_local.php` which checks `$_SERVER ["REQUEST_URI"]`for URLs which shouldn't have the debug kit.